# How to make an interactive list with python + tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Well, I want to make a program that takes a set of variables from a database and shows them in a list. I was thinking about using the Listbox widget, but when I tried it before it didn't show itself as really interactive. What I'm going for is a list that, when an item is double-clicked, will show some more information about said item in a window. Also, I want it to be organized, so that it shows, when still in the list, the items informations in their boxes, and not in a single string, as in the Listbox widget.
As it is probably obvious by now, I'm a beginner with tkinter, so this would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [idlelib.ScrolledList](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/jython/CPythonLib/idlelib/ScrolledList.py)

```
110    # Methods to override for specific actions
111
112    def fill_menu(self):
113        pass
114
115    def on_select(self, index):
116        pass
117
118    def on_double(self, index):
119        pass
```

You can subclass it or you just put your methods into the created object. Are these the methods you need?

Comment: Though it is not possible with List boxes to do something like scrolled frames. Some people use a Canvas for this into which they plant a frame that can be scrolled pixel-wise by scrolling the Canvas.